# Exchange Server 2010 mailbox audit search

Tags: exchange-2010

I want to perform mailbox audit search for mailbox owner's actions. I found one command on technet

***Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity firstname.lastname -LogonTypes Owner -ShowDetails -StartDate 11/27/2014 -EndDate 11/27/2012 | Where-Object {$_.Operation -eq "Create"}***

I am trying to get output for mailbox owner's action for his mailbox like sent or received mails. 
Is there any other option to check mailbox owner has sent to or received emails from whom for specific time period? above mentioned command does not give any output

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a record of messages sent and recieved then get-messagetrackinglog is probably the command you're after.

Comment: You can also easily do this from EMC Toolbox if you're lazy like me and want to quickly select your criteria.